# What is the proper way to return a memory stream to front end for the user to download the file?

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I use MS Graph to return a memory stream to my backend from an API call however I am not sure how to actually send that to the front end for the user to download? On my front end I basically have a button to call my API on my backend so the user can download the file.

My code so far for the backend is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadVersionHistory([FromForm] string FilePath, [FromForm] string VersionId)
    {

        var fullPath = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, FilePath);

        //upload new file to folder structure
        using (var memoryStream = await oneDrive.DownloadDriveItemVersionInfoAsync(SharedDriveID, Path.Combine(fileDirectory, FilePath), VersionId, "path"))
        {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return Ok(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

On my vue front end I use the following axios request to call the api then I have a download function I usually try to use that has a URL.

```
            downloadVersion(value) {
            const formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('FilePath', this.versionFilePath);
            formData.append('VersionId', value);

            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: window.location.origin + '/Documents/DownloadVersionHistory',
                data: formData,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    "RequestVerificationToken": document.forms[0].querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value,
                }
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status == 401 || error.response.status == 402 || error.response.status == 403) {
                    window.location.href = error.response.headers.expiredtokenredirecturi
                }
                console.log(error.response.data.error);
            });
        }
```

Then for my download function I would use the following:

```
            downloadURI(uri, name) {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = name;
            link.href = uri;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            delete link;
        },
```

However this only works if I have a URI but if I am returning a memorystream from my API request I do not have a URI to link to like some of my other MS Graph requests. If it is of importance I am using the following MS Graph SDK call:

```
                        response = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Root
                                .ItemWithPath(PathOrDriveItemID)
                                .Preview()
                                .Request()
                                .PostAsync();
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `using` on the stream as ASP.Net will handle that in this case, since you are just returning it out